# Debugging help: preInit event fires but init does not and there is no error

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I'm trying to debug an issue where my fancytree integration fails to work. I have the same code working in other spots on my site, but in one case my tree does not load.

I've turned on `debugLevel` to 4 and have been looking for events to determine where the failure occurs. The event `preInit` fires as does `nodeLoadChildren`, but the event `init` does not fire.

I threw a few debugging lines in and it seems like `tree.render()` is where things are getting stuck. What else can I review to help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the debugger call in you JS files where you think its bottling out

```js
debugger;
```

This will force your browser to automatically pause at this break point where ever this line of code is, from there you can strep though your JS code, using firefox or chrome debugger, try adding watchs to and the console to run parts of your code, console.log is ok (i assume when you say debugging lines that's what you mean). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the place in which the code fails is part of the fancytree lib and not my own code. I'm not understanding why the code in the lib fails without throwing an error in the console to begin with.

Comment: Have you tried asking on there github page: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues
Its hard to suggest anything without knowing more, I suspect it it works else were on Your site then try any wok out what's different about this one, is it a configuration issue with how its been set up ?

Comment: I did, but as soon as I go to add an issue the helper text say: "If you are going to ask a question, please use Stackoverflow instead:

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fancytree"